# Create a modal dialog confirmation that an email was sent from a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, response, modal-dialog

Basically the setup is as follows.  I have a simple contact page.  Users select email recipients and then fill in the message subject and text.  When they click submit the form is submitted using jQuery and a ajax call is made that returns the success (or failure) that said message was correctly processed and sent by the php script.

Currently the code looks like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var options = { target: '#results' }; 
            $('#classemail').submit(function() {
                $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
                return false; 
            });
    });
    function fade(div_id, button) {
    if(button.value == 'Send') {
        $('#'+div_id).empty().show().delay(7000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
        }
```

The sends the form and the html response is displayed in the results div.

```
<div class="results" id="results"><div>
```

pretty basic...  The issue is that I would prefer to do this response back with a modal dialog box since having the div handle it requires real estate on the page and it is not as evident or intuitive as a modal dialog box would be.  To that end I have attempted to add such functionality, but frankly, I am probably a little beyond my current understanding of jquery and how to accomplish this.  Is this achievable?  Can someone point me in the right direction or should I be considering other ways of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the result is returned. u can init the div to become a dialog. the dialog will autoOpen by default. check [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for more info on how to configure it.
You can also destroy the dialog once you don't need it by calling `.dialog( "destroy" )`

Remove the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state. However you might want to empty the div before destroying the dialog because it'll become visible.

```
$(".results").dialog({modal:true});
```

Comment: I am still not sure I follow exactly were to append the dialog call into my existing code. Does it need to occur before the function to initialize or does it need to be in the function itself.

Comment: You can initialize the dialog once you injected your "result" into the <div class="results">